# Retrieving a list of all metadata types

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, metadata-api, metadata

I am trying to get a list of all metadata types in an org to put into a picklist within a lightning component. I know outside of Salesforce you can use the describeMetadata() call to get this information but after reading the documentation, it doesn't look like this is available to call from Apex.

Is there any way to get this list via Apex, Visualforce or LWC?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch picklist values?

Comment: In the end they will be used in a picklist. All I need is something to return a list of strings with the names (ie ApexClass, PermissionSet, etc...)

Comment: So are you trying to modify apex class access from apex?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I just need a list<string> of these values:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm

Answer (score 0):

All metadata are not exposed to Apex. You need to use a callout to access metadata API in apex.

This repository you need to use to get that list.
[Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)